# Focus on Div Textbox at Page Load (Mobile Browsers)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contenteditable div textbox and I want the element to have focus on page load, so that the blinking cursor is visible. Therefore I used the JavaScript below.

Unfortunately, it is not working mobile (ios Safari / Chrome). Is there any way to make it work in mobile browsers? So that on page load the cursor is inside the element and the keyboard is already expanded?

html:

```
<div id="mytext" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-multiline="true" aria-labelledby="txtboxMultilineLabel" aria-placeholder="Statement-Placeholder">Type Here!</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("mytext").focus();
};
```